# Object Detection Label Map Item 'str' Object Has no Attribute 'item'

Tags: python, object-detection, object-detection-api

I have trained a custom images using Tensorflow Object Detection API and I run the object detection tutorial using trained data. I am having an error related the the Loading Label map. I have checked the label image file and it seem to be ok with its dictionary content. I cant quite understand why the error occur.

Code:

```
# What model to download.
MODEL_NAME = 'new_graph.pb'

# Path to frozen detection graph. This is the actual model that is used for the object detection.
PATH_TO_FROZEN_GRAPH = MODEL_NAME + '/frozen_inference_graph.pb'

# List of the strings that is used to add correct label for each box.
PATH_TO_LABELS = 'training/labelmap.pbtxt'

NUM_CLASSES=3

detection_graph = tf.Graph()
with detection_graph.as_default():
  od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()  
  with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_FROZEN_GRAPH, 'rb') as fid:
    serialized_graph = fid.read()
    od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
    tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')




category_index = label_map_util.convert_label_map_to_categories(PATH_TO_LABELS , max_num_classes=NUM_CLASSES, use_display_name=True)
```

Error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-7acf82e14013> in <module>
      1 #category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index_from_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS, use_display_name=True)
      2 
----> 3 category_index = label_map_util.convert_label_map_to_categories(PATH_TO_LABELS , max_num_classes=NUM_CLASSES)
      4 

D:\me1eye\New folder\29082020\models\research\object_detection\utils\label_map_util.py in convert_label_map_to_categories(label_map, max_num_classes, use_display_name)
    118       })
    119     return categories
--> 120   for item in label_map.item:
    121     if not 0 < item.id <= max_num_classes:
    122       logging.info(

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'item'
```

labelmap.pbtxt file:

```
item {
    id: 1
    name: 'Cat'
}
item {
    id: 2
    name: 'Grabes'
}
item {
    id: 3
    name: 'Olive'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Need to change the following:

from utils import label_map_util

---->from object_detection.utils import label_map_util

from utils import visualization_utils as vis_util

---->from object_detection.utils import visualization_utils as vis_util

Answer (score 0):

When using `convert_label_map_to_categories`, you need to load the map data first with `load_labelmap`. Your code is processing the filename instead of the file data.

Try this code:

```
label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS)
category_index = label_map_util.convert_label_map_to_categories(label_map, max_num_classes=NUM_CLASSES, use_display_name=True)
```

Comment: code didn't work I have got error                                                                                                            AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-65c38b2026c1> in <module>
----> 7 category_index = label_map_util.convert_label_map_to_categories(label_map, max_num_classes=NUM_CLASSES, use_display_name=True)
--> 133       if item.keypoints:
   
AttributeError: keypoints

Comment: Check this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62296937/attributeerror-keypoints-object-detection-using-tensorflow-1-14

Comment: I have checked the post. I have replaced the new label_map_util.py in utils file to old code as suggested in the post. and I added the following commands:  label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS)
categories = label_map_util.convert_label_map_to_categories(label_map, max_num_classes=NUM_CLASSES, use_display_name=True)
category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index_from_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS, use_display_name=True)                                                                                                                Same error: AttributeError: keypoints